# How to transform GPX-tracks into elevation-tracks with any GIS?

Tags: gps, dem, elevation, gpx

I have a GPS track in GPX format available from a recent bike tour and I need and want to do some analysis on the tracks. I'm wondering whether there is any way to transform the GPX data into an elevation model/graph like this (blue):

[image]

I created this image above using the german platform [komoot.de](http://komoot.de) where you can upload your GPX tracks but it's not customizable or in any way editable/scalable/exportable.

Are there any tools to achieve this? (The pink speed graph is optional.)

Comment: Example Snowdon Wales, http://www.bikehike.co.uk/mapview.php?lnk=http://uk3peaks.com/snowdon/pygtrack.gpx substitute with your gpx file. Click Elevation or Gradient Option.

Comment: @Mapperz, that is a great link and interface!

Comment: Tip with bikehike you can scroll across the Elevation/Gradient Chart with the mouse cursor that position is then shown on the map interactively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a Python approach, try [gpxplot](https://code.google.com/p/gpxplot/) available from code.google.com.  The script is available [here](http://gpxplot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gpxplot.py) and the online interface is located [here](http://gpxplot.appspot.com/).

[image]

Try using [GPS Visualizer](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/elevation).  The [profile](http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/profile_input?add_elevation=auto) tool looks like what you may be interested in.

[image]

Or, [Maplorer](http://www.maplorer.com/view_gpx.html): View GPX file on map + elevation

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with ArcGIS 10.1.

- run GPX to Features tool (converts GPX files to points features class)
- run Points to Line tool (converts points FC to line FC)
- run 3D Analyst tool: Stack Profile (creates a table of elevation AND with the optional output graph, provides the profile as a graph)

So you'll need ArcMap 10.1 basic /w 3D Analyst.[image]

Answer (score 3):

From the comment earlier
Bike hike has the ability to parse gpx from a web location and renders this on the google map but also creates Elevation and Gradient profiles:

Miles and Kilometers supported

Other options:

```
Add Course-point
Drag edit mode
Reverse the Route
Map Size
```

[image]

This is an Example of a trail up Snowdon Mountain in North Wales.

http://www.bikehike.co.uk/mapview.php?lnk=http://uk3peaks.com/snowdon/pygtrack.gpx

Comment: What do you mean, "drag edit"? I can seem to drag neither waypoints, nor the route itself... Also, there doesn't seem to be a way to remove a waypoint other than refreshing the page, resetting it to the initial view (rather poor user experience).